# .FIND function with .FIND and Offset()

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am writing a code in Excel for a 3 sheets, sheet 1 will display the data that does not appear in Sheet2 from Sheet3, in order to acomplish this the code will be the following;

```
Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Set r = Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(1, 1), Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
Dim curRowSheet1 As Long

curRowSheet1 = 1

For Each cell In r
    Set rFind = Sheet2.Range("A:A").Find(cell.Value)



    If (rFind Is Nothing) Then
        cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheet1.Cells(curRowSheet1, 1)
        curRowSheet1 = curRowSheet1 + 1
    End If
Next cell
```

NOTE: I am trying to include a second .FIND under line 9 "SET rFind" where if looks for the cell values in column ("A:Ä") and then it also verifies the values are the same from column ("B:B") from both sheets 2 and 3, I am thinking I can use the Offset() function to compare this data, any advise on this would be appreciated!!!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Range.Find`, I would recommend using `WorksheetFunction.CountIfs`

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ACell As Range

    For Each ACell In Sheet3.Range("A1", Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Cells
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheet2.Columns("A"), ACell.Value, Sheet2.Columns("B"), ACell.Offset(, 1).Value) = 0 Then
            ACell.EntireRow.Copy Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    Next ACell

End Sub
```